# How to remove a doorknob with no visible screws?

Tags: doors, lock

I have an exterior lock set with a knob on the inside. I can't get the interior doorknob off. It does not have a hole in the shaft of the knob in which you press a clip down to remove it. It's one of those where you pull the cover plate back away from the door and rotate an inner plate in the direction of the arrows. After I rotate the inner plate, what do I do next to remove the interior knob and the plate on the door. The interior plate is loose, so it seems to be out of its "Locked" position, but will not come off. I believe it's a Schlage lockset. It came with the house and is 22 years old.

Comment: Photos would help, so we know exactly what you're dealing with. It *shouldn't* be very complicated...

Answer (score 3):

post a pic . sounds like a kwikset titan and if it is you rotate cc about 15 deg and it should pop off. may be an old corbin where there are 2 rectangles at 12 o clock and six o clock. push them away from the latch with and the knob will literally pop off.

Comment: After looking closer it is a Kwikset (the deadbolt in the door is Schalge so I assumed the lower handset was the same brand).  I was able to get it off by using a hammer and screwdriver to rotate the plate farther. (If it doesn't work, hit it harder).

Answer (score 1):

Is there a lock cylinder on the other side? If so sometimes you need to use the key to remove the handle. Once you have the plate loosened, try turning the key beyond the normal resistance point.